# Tufte book in landscape

Tags: landscape, tufte

I took `doc/latex/tufte-latex/sample-book.tex` and added the `landscape` option:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{tufte-book}
```

The result PDF is in landscape mode but the text is vertically cut.

The log file contains

```
Class tufte-book Warning: Option `landscape' is not supported -- ignoring option
```

Why is landscape not supported?

Are there any workarounds?

My final goal is to have a wider margin for larger pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the paper sizes and layouts in the file [tufte-common.def](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/tufte-common.def), where the definition for `a4paper` looks like this:

```
\geometry{a4paper,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm,textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip}
```

The margin has a width of 49.4 mm and the text is 49 lines high. Since A4 is 297 x 210 mm you can make the margin 87 mm wider in landscape mode (297 - 210 mm) but you have to cut some lines (34 lines are fitting nicely). Which gives you the following geometry:

```
\geometry{a4paper,landscape,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=136.4mm,textheight=34\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip}
```

Just add it somewhere in your preamble:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\geometry{a4paper,landscape,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=136.4mm,textheight=34\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good luck with `tufte`, it's nice but a little stubborn...